# any possible method concatenate date and time as an integer

Tags: php

Is there any possibility to get get and time as an integer in php. 
in php am getting the date of the server as $todayDate and time as $currentTime

```
   $todayDate = date("Y-m-d"); // get current date value 
   $currentTime = date("h:i:s"); // get current time value
```

if current date is 2017-05-26 an time is 15:20

i require the integer value as 201705261520 
if there is any method please suggest.

Comment: If I may, What is your objective of combining / concatenating both `date` and `time` in your case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need any new method simply you can do something like this

```
$todaydate=date("Ymdhis");
```

Answer (score 1):

Just format the date the way u want

```
    $todaydate=date("Ymdhi");

    echo $todaydate;

  ?>
```

Results

> 201705261202

You don't need the second var `$currentTime....`

Answer (score 1):

https://eval.in/805793

```
var_dump(date("Ymdhis"));
var_dump(intval(date("Ymdhis")));
```